# How to check how I was hacked?

Tags: detection

Today I was notified by DigitalOcean that my droplet was hacked and a DDOS attack was generated from it. It was a droplet I used as a staging server for a webapp I will send to production later, and I just need to do `vagrant destroy` and `vagrant up` and I'll have my droplet again.

I don't need to recover my data, but I don't want this to happen when I'm in production, so I want to check how I was hacked, where can I start? Is there some standard steps to perform to do this?

If is relevant: It was a Ubuntu 14.04, with WP, Laravel and MariaDB in docker.

Comment: You should start by looking at the server logs and what was changed.

Comment: See also: [Serverfault's canonical question on "My server was hacked - how do I deal with a compromised server?"](http://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server)

Comment: That's exactly what I want! How can I close this question?

Comment: @IAmJulianAcosta I marked it as a duplicate, you can confirm that it's a dup and the question will be closed.

Answer (score 1):

Without checking too deep, I would say WP is the top risk in that list. I assume its updated, so you should check its settings and the plugins you have installed.

Check this article: https://isc.sans.edu/forums/diary/Wordpress+Pingback+DDoS+Attacks/17801

> Sucuri detected an interesting "reflective" attack using the
>   Wordpress Pingback feature to attack web sites [1]. Unlike other
>   reflective attacks that use UDP services like NTP and DNS, this
>   attacks uses the Wordpress Pingback feature.
>
> The intend of Pingback is to notify a site that you link to about the
>   link hoping that the site you are linking to will return the favor.
>   Some systems automate this and maintain automated lists linking back
>   to sites that covered their article. In order to implement pingback,
>   Wordpress implements an XML-RPC API function. This function will then
>   send a request to the site to which you would like to send a
>   "pingback"...